# print the sections of elf

Tags: elf

i need to write the function write_file:
This function, write_file(int fdOut, char *start1, char *start2), receives a file descriptor for the output file and two pointers to ELF file structures which were mapped to memory.
Loop over all section headers in the section header table, printing relevant fields (section name, offset, and length) to stdout (for debugging), and also write the respective section contents to the output file.

how do i "write the respective section contents to the output file" ?
it's always copy 0 bytes...

this is what i wrote:void write_file(int fdOut, char *start_a, char *start_b) {

```
 char *start1=start_a;
 Elf32_Ehdr *header;
 Elf32_Shdr *curr;
 char *curr_name;
 int i;
 int c;


write(fdOut , start1 , 52);
start1=start_a;

header = (Elf32_Ehdr *)start1;

for(i=0 ; i< header->e_shnum ; i++){
  start1=start_a;
 curr= get_shdr_from_index(i, start1); /*returns a pointer to the requested section header**/
 curr_name=get_section_name(i, start1); /*returns a pointer into the section header string table.**/

 printf("[ %d ] %20s %20x %20x\n", i ,
           curr_name , curr->sh_offset , curr->sh_size);


 if (c=write(fdOut, curr, curr->sh_size)<0) {
  perror("error");
  exit(-1);
}
printf("%d" , c);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Your first bug is here:

```
if (c=write(fdOut, curr, curr->sh_size)<0) { ...
```

Read about operator precedence [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++). What you meant to write:

```
if ((c = write(fdOut, curr, curr->sh_size)) < 0) { ...
```

Your second bug is that you are asked to write *section contents* to fd. But you are writing section *header*, and not the contents. The contents is to be found in the original file, at offset `curr->sh_offset`. That data may not be present in memory at all, so you'll likely need to `lseek` in the original file to and `read` the data from there, before you can `write` the data to the output.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-O binary` output format:

```
objcopy -O binary --only-section=.text foobar.elf foobar.text
```